# How do I initiate request to another Controller(with fresh RequestContext+Request) from within a ASP.NET controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where I need to call another controller, pretending to be a wholly new request(so with new cookies, URL and query params) and return its response.

So:

Web request -> ControllerA.Action -> generate some parameters to call another controller -> init ControllerB-> call ControllerB.Action and get View -> return View

I've simplified the scenario so please don't focus too much on that. I've used the following solution to create ControllerB and call it, but the issue I'm facing is that the HttpContext and HttpRequest info will still be from the initial web request. ControllerB has injected dependencies that read from this.Request and HttpContext.Current so it would grab the values for initial request:

```
        var controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(this.Request.RequestContext, "Second") as SecondController;
        return controller.Load();
```

Another possibility I am considering is if I can generate a new HttpRequest to my local server. Something like this:

```
            var secondRequest = new HttpRequest("", redirectLocation.AbsolutePath, redirectLocation.Query);
            // Add the headers for my new request
            secondRequest.Headers.Add(response.Headers);
            // Add the cookies for my new request
            httpCookies.ForEach(cookie => secondRequest.Cookies.Add(cookie));
            // Create controller with RequestContext from my new request
            var controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(secondRequest.RequestContext, "Second") as SecondController;
            return controller.Load();
```

This is not working currently, but I'd be glad to hear any ideas! Instead if I could construct ControllerB with a fresh Request that has the correct values, that would be the preferable solution. Any ideas or insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to make a HTTP call  to second controller action ?Extract the logic in other controller to a common class and call that from first controller action.

Comment: I have injected dependencies+action filters that look at HttpContext and this.Request to get cookies, URL and other request info. So the logic has global dependencies on the HttpContext being right for the second controller.

Comment: With the details you've provided, this sounds almost overly complicated. Can you give you give more details about what you're trying to achieve overall? (e.g. user logs in on page A then get redirected to Page B).

Comment: This is a overly complicated monolith, so you're not wrong. Goal is that User(which is the auth callback service) makes an unauthenticated request to page A, we auth in the background, internally make request for page B with the cookies and return page B. Yes I'm aware I could 302, but we are doing this specifically to avoid 302 for perf reasons. I'm not interested in simplify the problem domain, but asking if it's possible. :)